# Getting 404 Not Found after upgrading springboot version to 2.7.13 and spring-cloud-dependencies to 2021.0.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-function

I have spring-cloud-function implementation with spring boot

After upgrading to spring boot 2.7.13 and spring-cloud to 2021.0.1 and its higher version , rest endpoint throws 404 response

It works fine if we make spring-cloud version to 2021.0.0

[image]

Comment: Your question contains no information for us to diagnose what the problem my be. Please read this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask